# Git rebasing back/forth between two branches

Tags: git, workflow, branch, rebase

I have the following git workflow situation that raised the question -- can you rebase back/forth between branches?

The local branches (same as on origin):

- master
- branch_a (cut from master)
- branch_b (cut from branch_a)

Before all is said and done with this project, branch_a will be the canonical branch for the feature that will eventually end up in master.

branch_b has been rebased 1-2 times onto branch_a to pick up new work.  Ideally, all the work that it's in branch_b will remain there and find its way back into branch_a.

What's the best way to achieve that?  Is it OK to interactively rebase branch_a onto branch_b?

Comment: This strategy would be particularly useful for two developers who commit rapidly working on the same feature. If there were forced to work from a single feature branch, the prerequisites of each commit are too high.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to think of rebasing (IMHO) is to think of all the changes between the point where the branch split from something else and the branch tip as "a set of patches".  Rebasing, then, is really just taking all those patches and applying them to something else (which may be the new point of the original branch, or could be somewhere else in the tree entirely).

So, yes, you can rebase any branch to anything else **if** the patches apply cleanly to the new location.  Fortunately, it's actually fairly same to try since you can always abort the rebase if it fails because the patches don't apply properly (and are impossible to rectify because the new location doesn't have some critical component that the changes require).

Comment: So branch_b could be rebased onto branch_a to pick up the latest work, then changes could be made. When branch_b's changes are good, branch_a could safely be rebased onto branch_b to pick up said changes prior to being built into master?Leaving branch_b to exist as a slightly improved but frozen branch_a while branch_a continues forward before heading to master.